# Conditional (if-else) schema validation for body in Fastify?

Tags: jsonschema, fastify, ajv

Is it possible to do conditional validation on the `request.body` in Fastify? Fastify uses `ajv` for it's schema validation, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

I either get errors from strict mode saying I am missing the `type` key or I get it working, but I get the error in the request saying my value is required, even though it is there.

So my exact issue, I am trying to validate that a `state` value is present if the `country` value is "US".

I'm quite sure I have the syntax correct, but I feel I may have it in the wrong place... or it just don't work. My code looks like this:

```js
fastify.post("/user", {
  schema: {
    description: "Create a user",
    body: {
      type: "object",
      required: ["country"],
      properties: {
        state: { type: "string" },
        country: {
          type: "string",
          enum: ["US", "GB"],
        },
      },
      if: { properties: { country: { const: "US" } } },
      then: { required: ["state"] },
    },
    response: {
      //...
    },
  },
}, function (request, reply) {
  // do something
});
```

As mentioned, I tried moving the `if` chunk in to `properties` and even inside `country` but nothing seems to work.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this not possible?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Your code is working. What is the error?

Comment: No matter if I send the `state` value or not, I always get a 400: body must have required property 'state' back. Doesn't seem to see the value in the body at all?

Comment: checout the answer - I think you are looking in the wrong direction actually

Comment: Still no luck for me, always tells me I'm missing the `state` value in my body?!?!

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Fastify 4.15.0. I think the issue might be I stripped my example, if you add some other values to the body and require some of them, so it is not just country and state. Cos it seems like Fastify no longer sees the body at all, for example, if I have email as required it will then tell me I need to send email, when I am.

Answer (score 1):

Here a working example:

```js
const app = require('fastify')({ logger: !true });

const body = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    state: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    country: {
      type: 'string',
      enum: ['US', 'GB'],
    },
  },
  required: ['country'],
  if: {
    properties: {
      country: { const: 'US' },
    },
  },
  then: {
    required: ['state'],
  },
};

app.post(
  '/',
  {
    schema: {
      body,
    },
  },
  async (request, reply) => {
    return request.body;
  }
);

(async function () {
  {
    const res = await app.inject({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/',
      payload: {
        country: 'US',
      },
    });
    console.log(res.json());
  }

  {
    const res = await app.inject({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/',
      payload: {
        country: 'GB',
      },
    });
    console.log(res.json());
  }
})();
```

It will print:

```
{
  statusCode: 400,
  error: 'Bad Request',
  message: "body must have required property 'state'"
}
{ country: 'GB' }
```

Comment: Can we do the same using @sinclair/typebox?

Comment: IDK, I'm not a typebox user